# How to read bangla dataframe json file with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, project

Here my code look like

```
import codecs
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json(codecs.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/content_colab_access/quotes_test.json', 'r', 'utf-8'))
print(data.shape)
data.head()
```

I have different quotes in quotes_test.json. Here some parts of dataframe are,

```
[
    {
      "Quote": "যখন মানুষের খুব প্রিয় কেউ তাকে অপছন্দ করে না",
      "Author": "Humayun Ahmed",
      "Tags": [
        "bangladesh"," bengali"," humayun-ahmed "
      ],
      "Popularity": 0.381,
      "Category": "life"
    }
  ]
```

The error i found,

`ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value`

So my question to all of you what is the right way ?
I want to make the output like [image: Here]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding is not of required type.

```
pd.read_json(codecs.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/content_colab_access/quotes_test.json', 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
```

I recommend module [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to detect encoding.

Comment: thanks but I can't find Bangla Supported encodings from there.

Comment: It’s not about finding supporting encodings. But using *detect* to find the required encoding type for your source. Did you try with *utf-8-sig*?